# Reading Csv file with chinese characters in php

Tags: php, csv

I am reading a CSV file with Chinese characters,
and when i use print_r() it give me that type of array

```
Array ( [0] => PK!ȣ�4v�[Content_Types].xml ��(��T�n�0�W�?D�V��CUU]�-�L �IRP�h$.�����%�鮲�"�21J�"�{m�*�����H����z������f�����f�$ ) Array ( [0] => ORb^B�0�?)|��e\ɠ�Z��d����b2~�Bm [1] => %�;��*Y'�����**krE [2] => Tn��C2�Ear�>�T�b��4�T�4DÌqDl���?�t4�����*f�;+�@{�졗��F��io{S��mA�g�`�2k?Ly���&`Cwvݙ|��^z��v*u�Jw�}�\�Y�%����ACB$���qsk�MmQ6��-<���+ց�����_������ݥ㸋�G�|����g6 �����PK!�U0#�L�_rels/.rels ��(����N�0��H�C���nH���LH�!T�$����$@����Jc�����?[���iTb/Nú(A�3b{�jx��V�b"gi��aW��l_x���b���������#b4O��r��0Q�ahѓ�eܔ�=��P-<��j{�>�<���4Mox/�}b�N�@�;�v�Cf��ۨ�B�I�����"c�&�\O���8q"K��H��<ߊs@��.�h����<⧄�Md�a��T_��PK!�>����xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels �(����J�0����nӮ""��E��j}��L��m2㟾���ۅe���f���2���k�&�WP%�&��w ) Array ( [0] => ޚ���[=� ) Array ( [0] => &$���W�4�K��H"�xR��㣔d�����NҨ9��ɨ�Aw(7ey/���O�� ) Array ( [0] => ��ނh�����m�| ) Array ( [0] => �}D�g"$�4��F�Y��.2#���5�9��鳔�Y]b��d��@��%�s�"�ݚ0�tB��)���[����ȓ�����PK!�ك�N"xl/workbook.xml�QAN�0�#�k��I�Z5����P�ce�Mcձ-�!��荓=;����ruj%�B�V���Js�|l^��8�gR+ [1] => ��V��Ͳ������� ) Array ( [0] => h�7J]�`��DT���m���3w �o%͒dF[&� ) Array ( [0] => � ]ע�']u-*?�X�̇�]#��rY���aƼ�6�}�@$s�����i��ǫ���c'dd�$Z��|��c�:�7��E=�M�l;c[���}!9�⺏�!���j'�o��9���������q�G~0|3�D �Ƙ��j�U~/��am1�up��.v��8 [1] => �hTLV�[<��l��������PK!���xl/sharedStrings.xml�Uێ�0}G� [2] => ���V [3] => J�*a�V�R)��ٵ'����d��A�'���nʶ��>�3ǚ��$�zhr�J��r6��B�*�_o�o(�Ȕ`�V�� Xz�>[���*���{E���2;�(ǔڴݧ�"�`���6ѫ��"j�T�p�+L��%���z��ח4��LcL�H�YaG[`��Z-z��Y�j�� j����k���p!�{�;�f5>��K֐�ƫY�=p_� [4] => �� w )�$�zŏ��A��e~CE��f`���4�� �5�q�"�o4O>e��7Z�/8k��`IQ�`&5�n���2:*c�C���� ȸ4�?�}Ua}Ft'�y Ȫ�F�ie�����8(/�G�@�G��r$ �ȡ`�:r��9����.9y89;�<���)��40��3P!�K���vY��;�]�5�%a������n�ﺱ����m7�3+�ד��s�}�������Ou�������PK!;m2K�B#xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet1.xml.rels�����0E��Cx{�օCS7"�U�b��ۗ���{�e���p��6��<�f� [1] => Ժ��ch��{�-�A�8�� -<�a�.��NNJ�ǐX��Q$��~�ٱ� ��>��I�y0���Ь�jm�_�/N�� [2] => �}W�:=RY��}�H9�E��bA�w��k}�m���� ��PK!�%��Sxl/theme/theme1.xml�YOo�6��w tom'�u�ر��M�n�i��XS�@�I}��úa���0l+��t�&[����HJ��K��ՇD"|���#u�ڃ��C"$�q۫]�z��>�8h{w��K� ) Array ( [0] => �c�xL�ޜH�����]ś*$A�>����J%����a��ACM��ʈ���J����&M�;��4B�e� t�Y�>c~4$��� ) Array ( [0] => &�^������ ) Array ( [0] => �L1�bma]���u��t���(gZ��[Wvr���2���u{���`�M� [1] => E���F��� [2] => ���2�n�Q�����%�[�N��Je�D �>֗��f}{����7����v��t�d��%|�J�Yw�2O��ڡ�~J=�L8�-�o|���(��<�4� �ժX��}.��@����'d�}��.�F�b�o\��C�\Ҽ��MT��0��z�����S�����ώ�t�����--g�.����~����?�~����xY����'���y92h!ы/����ɋ�>����%�m�GE��FD�[��t3�q%'#q��Sg�v � ) Array ( [0] => �9fe�q�wW@�(^��wd�b�h �a��8g.J pC�*Xx8��r�bV�`|Xƻ�cǵ�YU3J��ݐ8b�3+��(�������Q��u���K>Q�ELKM2�#'��vi~����vl�wu8+�z��HH�J���:�)��� ~��L��\�E\O*�t@G�1��l�m��~C�*u��G.R(:-�ys^D��i7�QR��8 [1] => b?�SQ���*��q7C�;��+�}��ݧ�;4pDZ��� �K(�N��h�wŘQ��6�㶷 [SYJ�(��p��»�g�>�X_�x���wu�{���\>k�]X���y�}�钣�M�26PsFnJ�'K� [2] => �}����䇦$�Ǵ�;�@`� �>�*�8���i"�LI%\������x�ӕ=6��������u=� r2f� ��3c�� ������(��:�jZ�3s��L�s��*��U��ܚЅ �]��M8�k�p6���������x�"]$C<&�����>�'e�b. vJ|��y�X����ɾ��8�Ȯ��]�7�R�/�=�� [3] => .&'��Q�k5��q��&p���(�K��a�ݐ�� �S��d��L17 jpSa����S!��� 3���5'+�Z�zQ ) Array ( [0] => �H )�7 �5)���k�dB|UtvaD�ξ�����p|�Fl&0�_�*�3�n'LE�/p���m���&]����8fI��r�S4�d7y��`� ) Array ( [0] => �n���ί�I�R���3U�~��c�nrF:_�*�P����}���-p�Tp�l�r��ۜ�4LZéO� ) Array ( [0] => �� ) Array ( [0] => !�P�L��B���]�$K ��*�++��6�5���v�ꦚ�e��NƟ��f�(�MN1ߜ��6����&3(��a��d��E [1] => �U�z�<�{���E�Uϲ���V���)�9�Z[��4^kd�5���!J���?��Q�3�qBo�C~���M����m<�.�vp�����IYӦ���Z�Y_p���=al-�Y�}Nc�͙���ŋ4vja��vl����'S�&�A�8�|�*~x������1%M0�g%����<���ҭ���PK!5�՗�J? xl/styles.xml�[[��F~���`Y�c��V�.]���m�lԾ0�_�1���;��� [2] => �b��fm�|�;�9g����E���O7A��λ�i�� �gK/ ) Array ( [0] => �}~٢�R�(���.�Hf.�~rfĦ�i@4$�l�"�A%�.�����F'IV���k�'�bZ�֫1Y�qq`�kdU�䤫��t]Do��&������ yw���M3۵�~��I�x�7h�M��@������ټ�c�i�^3�&\�V0uO��K�{�ɝ�m<�P��Ϧύ�d��5����O_ȲU�(����aX-l���2�� [1] => ���ŉQ���X�X�p+�ݙ_�Ro߱XiT�I�`A [2] => VS�)J����N��\��*�#��;����q8m��t8l�r�i��K��A]�7m̦E2p�"Y�Y@�����p8tz��`���aF���/�f�132���{���uW6���A�3���r��4mӮ�۫M^h�*[�����L�i���@�W���o8��{U`�ɫM^e=��*�c���@�W�������C�^h���j����s�$]��\5z��K��&��_fع����f��Β [3] => K" [4] => o��^��V9��{b$z�hS���5��0i����s��Pe�V�N�i�����76 ���E����d��f$۞W\�!��s;_�$i� ) Array ( [0] => �)�`�f�V��(CBqD:��5��: ) Array ( [0] => #Tu�ԩ�\�%�v�o캃v��.��z@�xMĜshϳCj [1] => zv��MK�!�̍G�>lY���z�P���:�qS�q�ŧ�\�䍽����Q�zT���_(�����:��ni��ȍ�hZ��%��+� [2] => �R����A��2��:�?o�����&�ƮR��=����`G>뽘9��4��y�n����1>�>�H��5�#�a'e{\#{�Z�.Z�#Δ�7����Ġ>ŧI������( �`�J�"]9���ҕ" ) Array ( [0] => �2�� ])R�+G ) Array ( [0] => �Е" ) Array ( [0] => ���)zBW�9�ʑ���)PЕ!O�7N�-�m�7Q����k����>*-���[O����S�q�+�VJ�Iw����֩���1�]j����n�n3i����� [1] => `У�c�j�b�j<����Bl�o��m�V>�F�9�npw�1�X�mr ) Array ( [0] => �̱ [1] => �9���X@(�(c X0�X�c����PE ) Array ( [0] => [1] => �'r���0���m�U��S�G���He^"�#�m*_���HY_��ʗbq?R��X�\���HEY�B�]�U�ѡ�α������Q�UJ�*�D [2] => �G9Vm�X���X%�/���T�^����Q��b�u�~�m�U��ی*G���9 ) Array ( [0] => ��� %�(�kr�ۊQ��p���(�w��= ��f��m�T����o�Ż���Q���:�b/Kҽ��� ) Array ( [0] => NvzW�$�l$#X8U!�'^q�۳�Rq�@�a�� �������蜍�P��s9���I�C��V�s)�n��A��_ȑ#g $U���m�zU��S�R4�3=Pa�)"%�|p�X>��iD��!$j���k� fd y^w�*��K��i��&Z*<^��+�7E�o/�i�HS�M�шon��_��s!����#�~�]�Kof/՗c�b��! [1] => �_}�'����#=��YL�����K����PK!����<�xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml��[s�0��;�����ܤ��&��8�7d� F�����>Dz��$��#����U�EQ&2Y��e��"'�"d����)�b��L��(������F��R���2dK����R�xّ�ȴ2�Ŋ+}Y [2] => �2/��V��u�?�O2��0(l��y���>V"S�$�H���/�I^��0N�V��S�yȠ7�G���a��c"6ek�(�6����5�(�_��:i�>�w�w}��zt�M]�HY?R-�#��ŧ��Ӽ~7��^�ݭ�ow0���N [3] => ��#Uwrs*��R��w{s�G�Bn Io��y��7��V��.T;Y���Qw��jѧv��zX;jk��m���q[�6ik}�U3$@�H$�ڢG="�zB"!�DB����+ !@��D�J�#�;���=B P����� ����O@*{��T�>A��}� ) Array ( [0] => �OY���)+T�>e��ߧ�P� ) Array ( [0] => % ��P� ) Array ( [0] => e ��P� ) Array ( [0] => � ��P� ) Array ( [0] => � ���Շ��d������4�xg��;�+G���!{h��-c���l��-'fK�I�����Y�̖s���l�4[�̖k���l�5[�̖��ro�<�-�/�T�Of˳��b���-�<�E �"�`I��$X� [1] => R ��\�E0�"�`M��&X� [2] => � ��|�E@�"�`Ѫ�"���iY��#�qɋE��N��"��t��S4=J=� S}�Ϝ7��\m�����7�v|�̥T��U�΄��Y$���;���PO�^a��!+�q��v�����PK!�vA�� 'xl/printerSettings/printerSettings1.bin�a�a(f(e�c(g��)�@V1Pԃ!�A���!�Ke(b��%@�C �`F&�;.�����b)@��!� ��� ���Dc�d5q������|@'+�10��F���b�7�'$��9X��� 3T *ƯS1�ili ) Array ( [0] => &6 �|:z�A���� @��.tqd>(�@�D#���@���LL-H�d=�� Gln�Sd�·ɡ�&>4r����Ԁ� [1] => l`j��PK!&i�^EMdocProps/core.xml �(���]K�0���C�}��u:CۉʮV�Br���h�o�uu�^��ɓ�R [2] => v��>�yit�H��47B�M���e �G����w����%V�`��0���J�'��p� C ) Array ( [0] => t�$���^�R���~���[�C8�;/'�m͇ۤ}�_WOè���]q@�~? �aկr-A�v��B��5�7�b�I�Q� �U)w���������^�*K� [1] => N�qJj��삒���~5 ���?ƼNg4��3rb< ) Array ( [0] => ����P}��PK!Ie\o�docProps/app.xml �(��R�J1��Ò{�m����"=��Qbv��&Kf��~����nՓ9��{�yy���o����.�LLƩH�ې;���z�8� ��Lŭ��P�j�����I�����1Þ�"ĭ!n�F��p��m����鵄=��!�߂�W�5�_�<����5֊w.��N��jiM�Lׅ��< �L�¸�Z54k�R� �Oc*�w��.�Dc�3�xYK뛮�j��_C���PI&�îr���ғ���9��0pnq�|.&��'Cǝ��oo��7~�|g�rH��v��?=9���z�1��Z�&B����@�9�X�"���ȏ�߀�������t��Qr0S��7���PK-!ȣ�4v[Content_Types].xmlPK-!�U0#�L�_rels/.relsPK-!�>����pxl/_rels/workbook.xml.relsPK-!�ك�N"�xl/workbook.xmlPK-!��� ) Array ( [0] => xl/sharedStrings.xmlPK-!;m2K�B#\xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet1.xml.relsPK-!�%��S^ xl/theme/theme1.xmlPK-!5�՗�J? xl/styles.xmlPK-!����<� xl/worksheets/sheet1.xmlPK-!�vA�� '�xl/printerSettings/printerSettings1.binPK-!&i�^EM� docProps/core.xmlPK-!Ie\o�O#docProps/app.xmlPK&�% )
```

I encoded that CSV file with encode in UTF-8 without BOM.
For encoding, I just open csv file in notepad++ and then encode with **encode in UTF-8 without BOM** and then save it into CSV

Any kind of help will be appreciate.

Comment: please add proper array, so we can help.

Comment: ok i just edit my post, please check the array

Comment: are you sure they are Chinese characters? I think they are junk character!!

Comment: Actualy, i dont know i just upload csv file with some chinese characters

Comment: No change in array either i upload one row data or seven row data

Answer (score 1):

I just spent half a day trying to figure this out and noticed this is still open; so for anyone looking for the answer I found changing the encoding type of my .csv files fixed it. To do this, I opened the file in excel, and saved to replace the file, this time selecting the UTF-8 CSV encoding option. I believe you can also change the file encoding type in apps such as Notepad++ if you don't have an office.

Hope this helps! Sorry if I missed anything, it's my first time posting on this site :D

Comment: Please add code for answer this question

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30011420)